# Configure nginx reverse proxy in local node.js application

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, proxy, mysql, nginx

I know I'm close but I can't seem to connect my node.js app to my NGINX reverse proxy. My node app works locally and my config file tests ok. First small, question to I have to upload my nodejs app to my nginx vps?

I have a VPS running nginx with the following config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

What I want the node.js app to send the request to the proxy and then the proxy will serve the requests to my local apache, all the tutorials I find tell me to edit the nginx config and thats'it, but my config doesn't seem to work, what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Add `/` at the end of proxy_pass line:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
```

Comment: Ok thank you! But what next how do I connect my node app to my nginx vps?

Comment: send requests to `http://<your nginx host IP>/` or to `http://localhost/` if your node,js is on the same host

Comment: If you want to access to nginx through the Internet, you should open port 80 on your VPS firewall and address to its external IP: `http://<external IP>/`